# need to write htaccess file in windows server 2008

Tags: .htaccess, windows-server-2008-r2

I need to write htaccess file in windows server 2008.I created a htaccess file in localhost which works fine.

Need to know Where to create htaccess file in windows server 2008 R2.
I surffed,I that told to create web.config in IIS. 
Now I need to know where to create web.config in windows serer 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

Here is the possible solution for issue.

If possible than you can covert your htaccess to web.cofig file. It's IIS compatible and readable file.

Click [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig).

Comment: can you guide where to find web.config  file.

Comment: did you mean code editor?  notepad++(os windows server 2008 R2)

Comment: give me your email id I will send you a blank web.config file. You can edit it using notepad++.

Comment: I need to add  <Files feed.xml> 
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .xml 
 </Files> ..can you guide where to place it in your code